# figure out rowindex on a row I just inserted?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've got a vb project I am updating and it has a datagridview, a panel, and buttons along the bottom. The buttons control CRUD operations. The panel shows numerical up/downs and textboxes to represent the selected row.

I use some logic to keep track of current selected row and current row index for timer updates in the background. Upon delete I reset focus on the first row. Upon loading I set focus on first row. On update I keep current row focus.

Upon a good insert I would like to set the focus to the row I just inserted. But I do not know a way to determine what the rowindex value is for this freshly inserted row. My datatable which the datagridview uses is sorted on two id columns so it's not like the new entry will just jump to the bottom.

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the DataGridView [`RowAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx) event; its DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs parameter includes the [`RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowsaddedeventargs.rowindex.aspx) property which gives you what you need.

The event fires everytime a row is added, so you'll have to either wire the event up when you want to check for added rows, or ignore the event when you don't care when a row is added (such as when your grid fills with data).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to deal with the RowAdded event as Jay Riggs suggested, if you add it using a row object, as opposed to just Rows.Add, you should be able to pull that off of the row object after it's inserted.

```
Dim dgr As New DataGridViewRow()

DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr)
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(dgr)
```

This should also work for insert as well.

Comment: Your example is also helpful. I'm keeping it around because I know a couple places it will be of use. Thanks Yatrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually add rows to the DataGridView, then you can just use the return value from the Add method. Examples:

```
Dim newRowIndex As Integer = myDataGridView.Rows.Add()
myDataGridView.Rows(newRowIndex).Selected = True
```

No need to call IndexOf. If the DataGridView is bound to a DataSource then Jay Riggs' solution of using the RowsAdded event is the way to go.